# How to make that a drop down menu is not already open on page load

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having some problems figuring out how to make that the drop down menu isn't yet openend when I open the page. I'm still a beginner and maybe I'm just looking over it. Any help is welcome, would appreciate it!

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);
html
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

h1
{
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

h1 a { color: #888888; text-decoration: none; }

h1 a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

.content
{
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.admin-panel
{
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 color: #888888;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 41px;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.cog
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 6px;
 border: none;
 color: #888888;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.admin-text:hover, .cog:hover { cursor: pointer; color: #555555; }

input#toggle { display: none; }
input#toggle ~ .menu { display: block; }
input#toggle:checked ~ .menu { display: none; }

.menu a
{
 display: block;
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
 line-height: 40px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.menu a:nth-child( 2 )
{
 border-top-left-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:last-child
{
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:hover { color: #555555; }

.menu a:hover > .octicon { color: #555555; }

.icon
{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #000000;
 color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.octicon-person { margin-right: 16px; }
.octicon-graph { margin-right: 11px; }
.octicon-cloud-upload { margin-right: 11px; }
.octicon-pencil { margin-right: 13px; }

.arrow
{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border-left: 7px solid transparent;
 border-right: 7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>Administrator</h1>

<div class="content">
 <div class="admin-panel"><label for="toggle" class="admin-text">Admin Settings</label></div>
 <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
 <label class="cog octicon octicon-gear" for="toggle"></label>
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
   <a href="AfsprakenAdmin/indexafsprakenadmin.aspx" style="text-align:center;">Afspraken</a>
   <a href="AfsprakenAdmin/indexafsprakenadmin.aspx" style="text-align:center;">Afspraken</a>
            <a href="AfsprakenAdmin/indexafsprakenadmin.aspx" style="text-align:center;">Afspraken</a>
            <a href="AfsprakenAdmin/indexafsprakenadmin.aspx" style="text-align:center;">Afspraken</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You could use `:hover > `.

Comment: Just add attribute "checked" to your checkbox input: <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked>